# $(window) beforeunload works, but how do I get rid of it?

Tags: jquery, function, window, reload, onload

Opening my quiz I made this function to prevent user from messing up his progress.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){

return 'This will restart the quiz.';

});
```

Later on when the quiz is done, you need to press a button and the page reloads with parameter and it lets you see the answers and tips.

I want this event to be .off() before I click that button but nothing seems to work. I cant get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Boom got it, sorry guys.

Enable:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

Disable:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```